# Setting location.href in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am developing an Ember.js application whose initial page resides at:

`https://localhost:8443/`

I want to perform a redirect from JavaScript to the following location if the user is authenticated:

`https://localhost:8443/admin`

To do this, I write code as follows:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    var that = this,
        session = this.get('session'),
        sessionService = this.get('services').session();

    return sessionService.getStatus().then(function (sessionStatus) {
      session.setProperties(sessionStatus);
      if (/^\/[signup]|[forgotPassword]/.test(that.router.get('url'))) return;
      if (!session.get('authenticated'))
        that.transitionTo('signin');
      else
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/admin';
    });
  }
});
```

However, when I do perform this, the page browses to:

`https://localhost/admin`

I also tried `location.assign()` with the same result.

Why does setting `location.href` or `location.assign()` remove the port-number from the URL? Is this something that the Ember.js Router would be doing?

Any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the [documentation for the Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to see why. Essentially, there's ways to get *every* part of the URL and you just happen to be using the wrong one. Try one of these:

```
window.location.href = window.location.host + '/admin';
```

Or, more preferably:

```
window.location.href = '/admin';
```

The second way is nice because it allows you to forget about the base URL altogether and just worry about the relative path you need.

Also, Ember.js doesn't affect this kind of functionality at all, you're just dealing with the Javascript browser API.

Comment: Seems like I had made a mistake in the way I appended the path to `location.href`. Instead of writing `location.href = location.origin + '/admin/';`, I had written `location.href = location.origin + '/admin';`. The key was the trailing slash.